# How fix "A cache-control header is missing or empty" for favicon.ico file

Tags: .htaccess, caching

loading a webpage i get this error:

```
A 'cache-control' header is missing or empty.
```

for `favicon.ico` resource.
My `.htaccess` is so configured:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>

    Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff        
    Header unset Expires
    Header unset Pragma
    Header unset X-Powered-By

    <FilesMatch "\.(php)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "no-cache" 
    </FilesMatch>
    
    <Files "favicon.ico">
        Header set Cache-Control max-age=31536000    
    </Files>
    
</IfModule>
```

How i can fix it?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) page can help

Comment: Try `Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000, immutable` in 2nd block.

Comment: @anubhava nothing. i have tried to put it in format for htaccess but not work (err 500) and tried in three lines separated and i continue to display that error.

Comment: Is that your full .htaccess?

Comment: only it for test.